# Extend sda3 partition in openSUSE?

Tags: opensuse, vmware

I would like to extend the `sda3` partition in openSUSE 11.1 running on VMware.

My `df -h` has the following output:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             7.5G  5.0G  2.2G  70% /
udev                 1001M  180K 1001M   1% /dev
/dev/sda3              11G  9.7G   50M 100% /home
.host:/               298G  247G   52G  83% /mnt/hgfs
/dev/sr0              134M  134M     0 100% /media/GParted-live
```

My `fdisk -l` output

```
Disk /dev/sda: 37.5 GB, 37580963840 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4568 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b37e7

 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1         262     2104483+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2   *         263        1252     7952175   83  Linux
/dev/sda3            1253        2610    10908135   83  Linux
/dev/sda4            2611        4568    15727635   83  Linux
```

I already extended the drive in VMware and created an empty `/dev/sda4` partition, now how can I extend `/dev/sda3` to use the 15 additional GBs from the `/dev/sda4` partition?

Comment: What's the output of `fdisk -l`? It's a lot easier if the partition was at the end of the drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new partition (`/dev/sda4`) is just after `/dev/sda3`, which should make things straightforward.

Booting from a gparted live-CD (which, from your `/dev/sr0`, seems that you already have) and then resizing `/dev/sda3` should work, but **back up your /home first** (you might have hard drive corruption if you lose power, your virtual machine or host OS freezes/crashes, etc...).